# Searching Attachments in SharePoint 2010 Lists using CAML

Tags: list, search, sharepoint-2010, caml

I need help on searching attachments i.e Word Document, PDF etc which are attached to the list during inserting Item in SharePoint 2010 using CAML queries.
   I tried with this query

```
<Query>
   <Where>
        <Eq>
             <FieldRef Name="Attachments" />
             <Value Type="Attachments">WordDocument1.docx</Value>
        </Eq>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

im not able to get any results if i give this query.
Please help.

Comment: You can download the attachments by using SPWeb.GetFile(attachmentAbsoluteURL). As stefan mentioned below, you cannot download attachments directly using CAML.

Comment: @Ken can you please have a [look at this question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8814/tree-view-navigation-of-document-library), and suggest me how can I use PWeb.GetFile(attachmentAbsoluteURL) here !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the *Attachments* field of a SharePoint list does not store the attachments itself. This column only return whether a certain list item has an attachment or 
not.
The attachments are not stored in a SharePoint list. Therefore I don't think it's possible to retrieve them with a CAML query.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Im getting 1 if there is attachments else 0 is coming.

Comment: @Stefan i would like to get the file or its url attached to a grid-view. Currently for all other column I used CAML query to retrieve and attach to a grid view. Now how could I able to attach the corresponding attachment or its URL to grid-view...